# looking for shell script to monitor the remote java process and send an email alert when process got killed

Tags: python, linux, shell, scripting, centos

I am looking for a shell script which can ssh to multiple servers and grep the required process and send an email alert if it is not running .

I have 10 servers to monitor from the host and each server is having 8 applications running. Is that possible to setup the alert. I am on CEntos 7

Appreciate the earliest response !!

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#!/bin/bash
 
for host in $(cat /tmp/host.txt)
 
do
 
echo -n > /tmp/$host.txt
 
for process in $(cat /tmp/process.txt)
 
do
 
ssh $host "ps ax | grep $process | grep -v grep" > /tmp/$host.txt
 
        if [[ -s /tmp/$host.txt ]] ; then
 
        echo $process is running in $host
 
        else
 
        echo $process is not running in $host
 
        sendEmail -f   -t   -u "Subject" -l /var/log/sendEmail  -o message-content-type=auto  -m ""  -s  -xu  -xp 
 
        fi ;
 
done
 
done

## cat /tmp/host.txt

192.168.10.13
 
192.168.10.19

## cat /tmp/process.txt

java
 
snmp